# How can i read these 2 words specifically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code I'm trying to create involves the user inputting a colour and my output counts that colour.

My workaround:

```
a = input("Cars: ") 
for b in a:
  print("red:",a.count('red'))
  print("blue:",a.count('blue'))
  break
```

What I am trying to do is not read a word like `redish` as a colour. Since I am reading any word that has `red` in them. E.g. I don't want to count a word as blue when their input was something like `probluegram`. If they were to input a word like `probluegram` I want it to say blue: 0. Not blue: 1.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity, a simpler solution is just to use stemming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a string, and you are looping over that string; that means you get **individual characters**, not whole strings or words.

If you wanted to loop over `a` *per word*, you could split the string on whitespace:

```
for b in a.split():
```

This still won't do what you want, as you are counting substrings still. You'd have to compare these words to your target colours and count per colour:

```
blues = reds = 0
for word in a.split():
    if word == 'blue':
        blues += 1
    if word == 'red':
        reds += 1
print("red:", reds)
print("blue:", blues)
```

Comment: Can't believe i never saw through that! Thank you so much!